# Grub2 after Upgrade to Fedora Server 27

Tags: fedora, grub2

I upgraded to F27 and went to emergency shell after reboot.  After hours with google and experimentation, loaded recovery from install CD, found OS image and copied /usr/lib/os-release to /etc/os-release, and that, among other things I probably don't remember, got me to

```
grub>
```

So I found that I can boot if I do

```
grub> set boot=(hd0,msdos1)
grub> set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)
grub> insmod normal
normal
```

Then I get the kernel selection prompts (which say "dracut" instead of "Fedora" now?) and press 'e' to edit 4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64 and change "set root='hd0,msdos1'" to "set root='hd0,msdos3'" then hit ctrl-x to start and Fedora 27 finally boots.

My problem is I have to do that every time I reboot.  I ran

```
# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

It said it was successful but that didn't change anything. I still have to do the whole procedure to get the machine to boot and it is somewhat cumbersome.  Happily, we don't have to reboot it often.

My question is: How do I make these partition changes survive a reboot?

Thanks!

grub.cfg does seem to have the correct values, but I still have to do the above to get the machine to boot.  /etc/grub.cfg is linked to /boot/grub2/grub.cfg:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub2-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
set pager=1

if [ -f ${config_directory}/grubenv ]; then
  load_env -f ${config_directory}/grubenv
elif [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="${saved_entry}"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

terminal_output console
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  set timeout_style=menu
  set timeout=5
# Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
# unavailable.
else
  set timeout=5
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/01_users ###
if [ -f ${prefix}/user.cfg ]; then
  source ${prefix}/user.cfg
  if [ -n "${GRUB2_PASSWORD}" ]; then
    set superusers="root"
    export superusers
    password_pbkdf2 root ${GRUB2_PASSWORD}
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/01_users ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'dracut (4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64) 27 (Server Edition) dracut-046-8.git20180105.fc27' --class generic --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64-advanced-14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    fi
    linux16 /vmlinuz-4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64 root=UUID=14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb ro rhgb quiet 
    initrd16 /initramfs-4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64.img
}
menuentry 'dracut (4.11.12-100.fc24.x86_64) 27 (Server Edition) dracut-046-8.git20180105.fc27' --class generic --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.11.12-100.fc24.x86_64-advanced-14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    fi
    linux16 /vmlinuz-4.11.12-100.fc24.x86_64 root=UUID=14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb ro rhgb quiet 
    initrd16 /initramfs-4.11.12-100.fc24.x86_64.img
}
menuentry 'dracut (4.11.10-100.fc24.x86_64) 27 (Server Edition) dracut-046-8.git20180105.fc27' --class generic --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.11.10-100.fc24.x86_64-advanced-14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    fi
    linux16 /vmlinuz-4.11.10-100.fc24.x86_64 root=UUID=14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb ro rhgb quiet 
    initrd16 /initramfs-4.11.10-100.fc24.x86_64.img
}
menuentry 'dracut (4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64+debug) 27 (Server Edition) dracut-046-8.git20180105.fc27' --class generic --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64+debug-advanced-14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    fi
    linux16 /vmlinuz-4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64+debug root=UUID=14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb ro rhgb quiet 
    initrd16 /initramfs-4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64+debug.img
}
menuentry 'dracut (4.11.12-100.fc24.x86_64+debug) 27 (Server Edition) dracut-046-8.git20180105.fc27' --class generic --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.11.12-100.fc24.x86_64+debug-advanced-14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    fi
    linux16 /vmlinuz-4.11.12-100.fc24.x86_64+debug root=UUID=14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb ro rhgb quiet 
    initrd16 /initramfs-4.11.12-100.fc24.x86_64+debug.img
}
menuentry 'dracut (4.11.10-100.fc24.x86_64+debug) 27 (Server Edition) dracut-046-8.git20180105.fc27' --class generic --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.11.10-100.fc24.x86_64+debug-advanced-14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    fi
    linux16 /vmlinuz-4.11.10-100.fc24.x86_64+debug root=UUID=14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb ro rhgb quiet 
    initrd16 /initramfs-4.11.10-100.fc24.x86_64+debug.img
}
menuentry 'dracut (0-rescue-a9f8b0f7c9ac492ea0ca157a4e1f3d7b) 27 (Server Edition) dracut-046-8.git20180105.fc27' --class generic --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-0-rescue-a9f8b0f7c9ac492ea0ca157a4e1f3d7b-advanced-14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb' {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    fi
    linux16 /vmlinuz-0-rescue-a9f8b0f7c9ac492ea0ca157a4e1f3d7b root=UUID=14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb ro rhgb quiet 
    initrd16 /initramfs-0-rescue-a9f8b0f7c9ac492ea0ca157a4e1f3d7b.img
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_ppc_terminfo ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_ppc_terminfo ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Output of blkid:

```
 [root@vh02 ~]# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="348d6d2c-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="home" UUID="5c592a5a-9819-40d5-a1aa-9e04688cecfa" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="348d6d2c-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="348d6d2c-03"
/dev/sda5: UUID="4f19f0d8-badf-4dd3-8105-0bfb3d12609c" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="348d6d2c-05"
```

Comment: Where is your partition table? Where is the content of your `grub.cfg`?

Comment: Added grub.cfg.  The partition table is on /dev/sda.  MBR according to parted -l, msdos1 aka /dev/sda1 mounted as /boot. msdos3 aka dev/sda3 is mounted as /

Comment: Well, that's interesting. Are you sure that /dev/sda1 is actually mounted?

Comment: Yes.  Applicable output of mount:
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

Answer (score 0):

If your /boot volume is on sda1, then your menu entry is definitely wrong. Look at the following top entry:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'dracut (4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64) 27 (Server Edition) dracut-046-8.git20180105.fc27' --class generic --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64-advanced-14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5576283-fa19-4b57-8c1a-4d44227e8b8c
    fi
    linux16 /vmlinuz-4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64 root=UUID=14f0dc3e-9ff4-4051-a8a8-302730b552fb ro rhgb quiet 
    initrd16 /initramfs-4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64.img
}
```

set root='hd0,msdos3' is incorrect. That should read 'hd0,msdos1'. This is what's pointing GRUB at your /boot partition, while the root= argument to your kernel (the line that starts with "linux16") should point to the filesystem UUID of /.

You probably have grub files on / as well as /boot, and during your upgrade /boot may have been unmounted. It's hard to say from the information given, but that's a common culprit. Fixing this may be as easy as regenerating your grub configuration with `grub-mkconfig` while making sure /dev/sda1 is mounted at /boot. You might also want to clean up the /boot directory on the / filesystem first if that's really the problem.

Your dracut issues are separate but related. I would look to the root=UUID= line of your kernel, and make sure that the UUID there is actually to your root filesystem and not to something else. `blkid` within a running system will print the UUID next to the mounted point as well as other details. Your menu and other things are saying 'dracut' because the grub config generation didn't detect a fedora installation properly. Again, this may be due to an unmounted /boot or even a bind mounted / during `grub-mkconfig`.

Comment: I added output of blkid which correctly shows /dev/sda1, aka msdos3 UUID in line starting with "linux16."  Where would I look for grub files on / ?

Comment: Oops! That was a typo: blkid shows UUID of /dev/sda3 aka msdos3 as / which is correct.  /boot is /dev/sda1 aka msdos1

Comment: BTW: the posted grub.cfg is the result of:
" grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg" on the running system with correct mounts.  It seems something else is loading?